# Ecuaciones en kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Estoy haciendo un programa para la escuela el cual calcule la atenuación de presión sonora a cierta distancia.
El problema es que al ingresar los datos y que haga el calculo, no me arroja el resultado deseado cuando presiono "calcular" me arroja otro resultado deseado

El codigo que uso seria:

```
     fun proceso(view: View)
    {

        val btnresul = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonProceso)
        btnresul.setOnClickListener {

                //Constantes
                val k = 1.4
                val rcon = 8.314
                val mol = 28.966
                val p0 = 0.00002
                //Datos a ingresar
                val temperatura = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTemperatura)
                val niveldepresionacustica = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editPresion)
                val distancia = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editDistancia)
                val humedad = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editHumedad)
                val t : Double = temperatura.text.toString().toDouble()
                val npa: Double = niveldepresionacustica.text.toString().toDouble()
                val r : Double = distancia.text.toString().toDouble()
                //Datos obtenidos por formulas
                val p : Double = p0 * Math.pow(10.0, npa.div(20))
                val peffe : Double = Math.abs(p) * Math.sqrt(2.0)
                val c : Double = Math.sqrt((k * rcon * t).div(mol))
                val q : Double = p.div(Math.pow(c, 2.0))
                //Formula general
                val leyinvcuad : Double = ((Math.pow(peffe, 2.0) * 4*Math.PI * Math.pow(r, 2.0)).div(q * c))
                val resul = leyinvcuad.toString()

                var verresultado = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewResultado).apply {
                    text = resul

            }
        }
    }
```

[image]
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

Comment: Te sugiero agregar el código o layouts como texto, no como imágenes, ¿?Cual es la formula que usas? saludos.

Comment: Agrega el código en texto y no en imágenes. Además coloca la fórmula de lo que pides.